# Runtime Error 2465 Cant find my Field "Number"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to open a specific recordset in a print preview but Access can't find my variable.
I'm getting a `Runtime Error 2465`. The variable I want to Access is in a public Sub.

```
Public Sub PrintPreview_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acViewPreview, , "Number1 = " & Me!Nummer2
End Sub
```

Comment: In reply to a proposed answer you write "no its not the typo i just edited the variable for stackoverflow. Original Code -> DoCmd.OpenForm "Personenkonto", acViewPreview, , _ "[Belegnummer] = " & Nummer" -- If you want people to help you you *MUST* provide accurate information. Your code sample should show exactly what the problem is - you can't use "Number" in the title and then not show corresponding code!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have a typo.

where says  "Me!Nummer2" doesnt you meen  "Me!Number2"

thanks

Comment: no its not the typo i just edited the variable for stackoverflow. Original Code -> DoCmd.OpenForm "Personenkonto", acViewPreview, , _
                      "[Belegnummer] = " & Nummer